# Display formatted paragraphs on Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, text

I'm trying to build a blog and I'm stuck at something.

When I add a post, I'm adding spaces and building block textes, like paragraphs, and I want to display them exactly in the same form as they were written.

eg:

"*Lorem ipsum lorem ipsumipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum* "

is rendered as one line:

"*lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum* "

How can I do that? Thank you

Comment: You'll need to either add pre tags around the text(not realy recommended) or replace enters etc. with the right tags

Comment: When you `dd($text)`, what do you see? Do you see multi-line tags?

Comment: I'm going to make the assumption that you're doing the writing in a `<textarea>` and rendering the stored output in a blade template file or just returning it as a request response. If that's the case you probably you might just need to use something like `nl2br($value)`.

Comment: Also when writing question please provide code snippets relevant to your particular issue, because you won't get many answers if people don't get enough information about your problem.

Comment: You can use `<pre>` HTML tag to show pre formatted text.

Comment: Thank you, @Bogdan! It worked like a charm. Will be more careful next time when I ask, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to add some simple CSS to the page. Add a class name to the wrapping html tag:

```
<div class="class-name">
    *Lorem ipsum lorem ipsumipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem 
    ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum*
</div>
```

And add the following CSS:

```
.class-name {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

pre-wrap allows:

> Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are broken at newline
>   characters, at < br>, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

While the default, normal, is the following:

> Sequences of white space are collapsed. Newline characters in the
>   source are handled the same as other white space. Lines are broken as
>   necessary to fill line boxes.

You can read more about the white-space attribute [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

Alternatively, you can use the [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) html tag to achieve a similar outcome.

> The HTML  element represents preformatted text which is to be
>   presented exactly as written in the HTML file. The text is typically
>   rendered using a non-proportional ("monospace") font. Whitespace
>   inside this element is displayed as written.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WYSIWYG tool like CKFinder or Summernote, and save the html in your db. Then render it `{!!$post->text!!}`